# WHY : Unable to lock the administration directory

Tags: apt, software-installation

I know that this is a "mainstream" question, i don't want to know what to do if i get this message, i already know that there are so many topics about it, I would like to now "why", why can't i open two terminal windows and type-enter two differents "sudo apt-get install" commands? Why does ubuntu have to "lock" this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run two instances of `apt-get install` they will try to write to the same files that will cause conflicts.

That is why the system does not allow to do it.